# State object in django

Tags: python, django, state, state-machine

My problem is as follows:

I am implementing a labeling system for a machine learning problem.
So in short: A complex object should get a simple label information (like a tag).
There should be just one label per object and the set of labels is limited and static.
(e.g.: I want to label all attributs of one animal objects to the information CAT, DOG, etc.)

So I have an item object. I want to save this as a tupel with one of my label-objects (myAnimal, label). This object should only carry ONE information (e.g. DOG). How can I accomplish that?
I thought of an object that holds some booleans and the one boolean I want gets set, but that seems to be not a nice solution since multiple booleans could be set.

I googled for a simple enum-like solution but found nothing satisfying.

It would be nice if you could help me out here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your labels are static and pre-defined:

```
TAGS = ((1,'DOG'),(2,'CAT'),(3,'HORSE')) # and so on

class MyThing(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   tag = models.IntegerField(choices=TAGS)
```

With this model, your thing can only have one tag, and you can get the associated tag for your object thus:

```
foo = MyThing.objects.order_by('?')[0] # get some random object
print 'My object is a ',foo.get_tag_display()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple model with some relations ?

```
class LabeledItem(models.Model):
   my_object= models.OneToOneField(Item)
   label = models.CharField()
```

The label property could also be a OneToOneField to for example a Label model which has a name as field property.

Comment: Yeah, but that would allow me to use **any** string as a label to describe my object. Not a discrete predefined set.

Comment: That's true, but django has a Field.choices property: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices which is probably what you want ?